# Notation package problem

Tags: symbolic, syntax, packages, custom-notation

I am using Mathematica 12.3.1 on Windows 10. I am trying to load the Notation package:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

and I get the following: [image]

It seems the package has a problem on the first load but not on the second?
Any ideas?

I have used the notation package before, without any problems

Comment: I can confirm that the package load with errors both in *Wolfram Cloud 13.0.1 for Linux x86 64-bit* and *Wolfram Engine Kernel 13.0.0 Windows*, which rules out an installation issue on the OPs side and points to an incompatibility between the latest version of the Kernel and the `"Notation"` package.

Comment: I think the problem with [`NotationPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) is an issue for Wolfram Support. And the scope of this question should be only to confirm which systems are affected by this [tag:bugs] which which are not.

Comment: @LukasLang Yes it does, thank you!